# Specialise zero template argument and one template argument version for the variadic template class

Tags: c++, c++17

I want a class which can accept zero or one template argument.
Like this

```
template <typename... A>
struct S;

template <>
struct S<> {
  S(){
      
  }
};

template <typename A>
struct S<A> {
  S(A a){
      
  }
};
int main()
{
    auto s1 = S();
    // compile error
    auto s2 = S(1);
    // okay
    auto s3 = S<int>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

C++17 has supported the deduction from constructor, but I get the compile error when I did not declare the template argument.
Is there anyway I can omit the explicit template argument ?

Comment: `struct S<>` doesn't have any parameterized constructor. How can you possibly pass an argument to the constructor when the constructor doesn't have a corresponding parameter?

Comment: Why not just write `auto s2(1)`?

Comment: I wanna a S type not int

Comment: I just realized *(after posting my answer)* that is could be labeld as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64184732/ctad-fail-to-deduce-template-argument-with-sfinae-in-partial-specialization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the [implicitly declared deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) only apply to the *primary* class template, **not** the specializations. That is why you need to use user-defined deduction guides in this case:

```
template <typename... A>
struct S;

template <>
struct S<> {
  S(){
      
  }
};

template <typename A>
struct S<A> {
  S(A a){
      
  }
};

// C++17 deduction guide:
template <typename... A>
S(A&&...a) -> S<A...>;

int main()
{
    auto s1 = S();
    // compile error
    auto s2 = S(1);
    // okay
    auto s3 = S<int>(1);

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bY1nfa74f